# Bootstrap 3 pills in side an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to combine  pills and accordion in bootstrap 3.

It seems to work file, but I have two issues.

1. if the accordion is open, when clicking on another tab the accordion closes.
   i would like it to close only when clicking on the active tab, otherwise i want it to show the clicked tab.
2. when clicking a tab on another accordion line, the tab in the previous line is still showing as active.

bootply code example:
[here](http://www.bootply.com/Yz0ty4ITIW).

```
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                        <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="red">
                            <h1>Red</h1>
                            <p>red red red red red red</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="orange">
                            <h1>Orange</h1>
                            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
                            <h1>Yellow</h1>
                            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                            <h1>Green</h1>
                            <p>green green green green green</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
                            <h1>Blue</h1>
                            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .panel-default {
            border: 0px;
        }

        .panel {
            border: 0px solid transparent; */
            border-radius: 0px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0;
            box-shadow: 0;
        }
```

Comment: please put code in your question for future reference.

Comment: Your going to need to implement some more specific code here to get this to work the way you want. The data-toggle="collapse" attributes are triggering a bunch of default open/close behavior. Also, you're leaning on default behavior for selecting active pills, so you'll need to be more granular. If you go to the docs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse and http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse and http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs, you'll see some more specific code you can use to trigger tabs activating and collapse divs showing/hiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you want to toggle the accordion only on the click of active tab.
you can use the collapse using javascript. Please find the working jsfiddle [Here](http://www.bootply.com/wbvWCthDHq#)

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading ul#tabs li a').click(function(){
  $("#accordion .panel-heading ul#tabsb li").removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active'))
  { $('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle'); }
  else
  {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse({toggle:false});
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
  }

});

$("#accordion .panel-heading ul#tabsb li a").click(function(){
  $("#accordion .panel-heading ul#tabs li").removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active'))
  { $('#collapseTwo').collapse('toggle'); }
  else
  {
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
  }
});
```

in the html part make following changes:

> 1. you are using two ul with same id tabs , change the id of the second ul to tabsb
> 2. the part `href="#collapseOne"` to `href=""` as we will trigger collapse using js
> 3. the part `href="#collapseTwo"` to `href=""`

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="red">
                <h1>Red</h1>
                <p>red red red red red red</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="orange">
                <h1>Orange</h1>
                <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
                <h1>Yellow</h1>
                <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
                <h1>Blue</h1>
                <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
          <ul id="tabsb" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#To" data-toggle="tab">To</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Four" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="One">
                <h1>One</h1>
                <p>One One One One One One</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="To">
                <h1>To</h1>
                <p>To To To To To</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Three">
                <h1>Three</h1>
                <p>Three Three Three Three Three</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Four">
                <h1>Four</h1>
                <p>Four Four Four Four Four</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Update:**

As Jesse Buitenhuis has suggested it will be better to use a single class. Add data-collapse-toggle=" collapseOne" to the ul. and use following js which solves both of your problem . js fiddle [Here](http://www.bootply.com/SfVaGUHmwJ)

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading ul li').click(function(){
  var target = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('collapse-toggle'));
  $("#accordion .panel-heading ul li").not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
  { target.collapse('toggle'); }
  else
  {
    target.collapse({toggle:false});
    target.collapse('show');
  }

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-collapse-toggle="collapseOne" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="red">
                <h1>Red</h1>
                <p>red red red red red red</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="orange">
                <h1>Orange</h1>
                <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
                <h1>Yellow</h1>
                <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
                <h1>Blue</h1>
                <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
          <ul id="tabsb" data-collapse-toggle="collapseTwo" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#To" data-toggle="tab">To</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Four" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="One">
                <h1>One</h1>
                <p>One One One One One One</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="To">
                <h1>To</h1>
                <p>To To To To To</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Three">
                <h1>Three</h1>
                <p>Three Three Three Three Three</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Four">
                <h1>Four</h1>
                <p>Four Four Four Four Four</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
i'm trying to do the same thing with UI Bootstrap and ran into some problem.

could you please take a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138544/ui-bootstrap-dynamic-accordion-than-contains-dynamic-tabs

thanks allot
Avi

Answer (score 2):

This solution can be re-used for as many panels in the page. Add `data-collapse-toggle=" collapseOne"` to the `ul`. The only issue here: I haven't found a solution for removing the 'active' state on the tab yet, so I used a 'selected' class instead. Any ideas are welcome, it would be better not having to use two classes.

Full working Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Nk0w3EuBxd

The Javascript:

```
$('[data-collapse-toggle] li').click(function(){

var target = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('collapse-toggle'));
  $(target).collapse({'toggle' : false }); //Fixes first time toggle error

  if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(target).collapse('hide');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(target).collapse('show');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript.

http://www.bootply.com/jsIK8OjCBK

JS :

```
$(function(){  
  var p1 = $('#collapseOne .panel-collapse');
  var p2 =$('#collapseTwo .panel-collapse')
  $(p1).collapse({toggle: false});
  $(p2).collapse({toggle: false});
  $("#collapseOne .panel-heading ul li a").click(function(){
    $(p1).collapse('show');
    $(p2).collapse('hide');
    $("#collapseTwo .nav .active").removeClass('active');
  });

  $("#collapseTwo .panel-heading ul li a").click(function(){
    $(p2).collapse('show');
    $(p1).collapse('hide');
    $("#collapseOne .nav .active").removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

HTML :

```
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-parent="#accordion">
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
                <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="red">
                <h1>Red</h1>
                <p>red red red red red red</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="orange">
                <h1>Orange</h1>
                <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
                <h1>Yellow</h1>
                <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
                <h1>Blue</h1>
                <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div data-parent="#accordion">
          <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#To" data-toggle="tab">To</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Four" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="One">
                <h1>One</h1>
                <p>One One One One One One</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="To">
                <h1>To</h1>
                <p>To To To To To</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Three">
                <h1>Three</h1>
                <p>Three Three Three Three Three</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                <h1>Green</h1>
                <p>green green green green green</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Four">
                <h1>Four</h1>
                <p>Four Four Four Four Four</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the active tabs to close when you click on them, modify Thibaud Graniers javascript to be something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#collapseOne .panel-collapse").collapse('show');

  $("#collapseOne .panel-heading ul li a").click(function(){
     $("#collapseOne .panel-collapse").collapse('show');
     $("#collapseTwo .panel-collapse").collapse('hide');
     $("#collapseTwo .nav .active").removeClass('active');
     if($(this).parent('.active').length){
        $("#collapseOne .panel-collapse").collapse('hide');
     }  
  });

  $("#collapseTwo .panel-heading ul li a").click(function(){
    $("#collapseTwo .panel-collapse").collapse('show');
    $("#collapseOne .panel-collapse").collapse('hide');
    $("#collapseOne .nav .active").removeClass('active');
    if($(this).parent('.active').length){
        $("#collapseTwo .panel-collapse").collapse('hide');
    } 
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Below is the final working code after a little editing:

Although i still have a small Issue:

when adding more then 2 lines, On the **first load** when clicking for example on "Blue", all other lines open a bit.

any advice?

Thanks 
Avi

The code:

HTML

```
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
                    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-pills" data-collapse-toggle="collapseOne" data-tabs="tabs">
                        <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="red">
                        <h1>Red</h1>
                        <p>red red red red red red</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="orange">
                        <h1>Orange</h1>
                        <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
                        <h1>Yellow</h1>
                        <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                        <h1>Green</h1>
                        <p>green green green green green</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
                        <h1>Blue</h1>
                        <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
                  <ul id="tabsb" data-collapse-toggle="collapseTwo" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                        <li><a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#To" data-toggle="tab">To</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Four" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="One">
                        <h1>One</h1>
                        <p>One One One One One One</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="To">
                        <h1>To</h1>
                        <p>To To To To To</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="Three">
                        <h1>Three</h1>
                        <p>Three Three Three Three Three</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
                        <h1>Green</h1>
                        <p>green green green green green</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="Four">
                        <h1>Four</h1>
                        <p>Four Four Four Four Four</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
                            <ul id="tabsb" data-collapse-toggle="collapseTree" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                                <li><a href="#Avi" data-toggle="tab">Avi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#Moshe" data-toggle="tab">Moshe</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#David" data-toggle="tab">David</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="Avi">
                                    <h1>Avi</h1>
                                    <p>Avi Avi Avi Avi Avi Avi</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="Moshe">
                                    <h1>Moshe</h1>
                                    <p>Moshe Moshe Moshe Moshe Moshe</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="David">
                                    <h1>David</h1>
                                    <p>David David David David David</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


          <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="">
                                    <ul id="tabsb" data-collapse-toggle="collapseFour" class="nav nav-pills" data-tabs="tabs">
                                        <li><a href="#Table" data-toggle="tab">Table</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#chare" data-toggle="tab">chare</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="Table">
                                            <h1>Table</h1>
                                            <p>Table Table Table Table Table Table</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="chare">
                                            <h1>chare</h1>
                                            <p>chare chare chare chare chare</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            </div>
```

JS

```
        $('#accordion .panel-heading ul li').click(function () {
            var target = $('#' + $(this).parent().data('collapse-toggle'));
            $("#accordion .panel-heading ul li").not($(this)).removeClass('active');
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
                target.collapse('toggle');
            }
            else {
                $('.collapse').each(function() {

                    if(!$(this).is(target[0])){
                        $(this).collapse('hide');
                    }else{
                        console.log('MATCH');
                    }
                });
                target.collapse({toggle: false});
                target.collapse('show');
            }
        });
```

bootply code example: [here](http://www.bootply.com/f9hxY5Ne9D).

Thanks allot

Avi